# Why doesn't this closure outlive var?

Tags: rust, lifetime

Consider the following Rust code:

```rust
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    bar();
    loop {}
}

fn bar() {
    let var = b"foo";
    thread::spawn(|| {
        write(var);
    });
}

fn write(d: &[u8]) {
    println!("{:?}", d)
}
```

To my understanding, `var` is on the stack of function `bar`, which no longer exists after it returns.

Still, the new thread accesses it afterwards and successfully writes the data.

1. Why does this work?
2. Why doesn't the Rust compiler complain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> To my understanding, `var` is on the stack of function `bar`, which no longer exists after it returns.

`var` is just a reference with type `&'static [u8; 3]`. This reference value is what is on the stack, not the string literal.

The **owner** of the byte string literal `b"foo"` is the **program binary**, which results in the string literal having a `'static` lifetime because it exists for the entire lifetime of the running program.

Answer (score 4):

The `b"foo"` value doesn't live on the stack actually. It is stored in the read-only memory of the compiled binary and has a [`'static`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/lifetime/static_lifetime.html) lifetime.

Consider this alternative example:

```
fn bar() {
    let var = format!("foo");
    thread::spawn(|| {
        write(&var);
    });
}

fn write(d: &str) {
    println!("{:?}", d)
}
```

That won't work (unless you add `move` before the closure), because `var` (of type `String`) *is* allocated on the stack.